# Envelope plot in excel

Tags: excel, join, plot, max, envelope

I am trying to plot the envelope (maximum) values of a series of data. What I need is not the maximum value of the y-axis as the value of x-axis increase but an envelope or spectrum which joins only the maximum points as the values of x-axis increase.
My data look like:
[image]

If I ask for the maximum y-values as the values of the x-axis increase, I will get this one (the black line is the maximum of all data as x is asceding):

[image]

But I need a line which joins only the next maximum points till x=30 and then the maximum values, which descend (from x=30 to x=100). The curve I need should be smooth and not follow the values of the data but only join the next maximum. 
The next curve is the envelope but only after the absolute maximum point. At the left of the absolute maximum point the envelope is not the wished one:
[image]

Comment: Are these curves a result of DATA or function calculations?

Comment: Also, at around x=45 you have a local maximum. Should your envelop reach that local maximum or only the one at ~x=38 and x=51?

Comment: @FDavidov these are plots from data. The envelope should reach only the one at x=32 and x=51.

Comment: I don't understand. Why only 32 and 51, and not 15, 24, 39, 51, 67...? In fact, the envelop should start at 0.

Comment: No, it is not only at x=32 or at x=51. These are points for example. It should start at x=0 and contain among other points the x=15, 24, 39, 51, 67. It was false expressed above.

Comment: Then, the solution I schematically explain in my answer bellow should fit. If it does, please mark it as such and (if you wish) up-vote it.

Comment: What I am not managing is the all point to the left or to the right. I am trying with arrys, index, match etc, but I am getting #nv (no value). Schematically I know also to describe it. With excel commands I cannot manage it. Do you have any suggestions about excel commands how to make it work?

Comment: Are you points in rows or columns?

Comment: each curve is one column

Answer (score 0):

After posting my questions (as comments), I think the following will do what you want (here I'm assuming I understood what you need):

1) At any point along the X axis, you already know how to recognize a maximum,

2) If (1) is correct, you will take into account a maximum (i.e. make it part of the envelope curve) if and only if:

```
 a) All the points to the right are lower than the current maximum, and/or

 b) All the points to the left are lower than the current maximum.
```

Intuitively, this should work.

EDIT:

Assuming that data is arranged in columns, say between B and D and rows 10 to 100, define in cell E10 the following:

```
  =IF(AND(MAX(B10,D10)>MAX(B9:D9),AND(MAX(B10,D10)>MAX(B11:D11)),MAX(B10,D10),"")
```

This formula will result into a value if you have a local maximum in rows 11 to 99 or blanks otherwise. Then, drag the formula till row 100 and voilà!!!

Note that the first and last point (i.e. rows 10 and 100) might yield a wrong result though. To prevent that, just alter the formula in those two rows.

Hope this is what you were looking for.

Comment: I suppose this can be done with index, match etc, right? But how exactly? How do I define the current max?

Comment: Well, in Excel it is going to be a little difficult if it comes from data points. From math, a maximum is where the first derivative is 0 and the second is > 0 (or <0; please check the books). Calculating derivatives from a series of data is perfectly doable, but in Excel it is going to be a little tricky. One way would be to check, at each point, if the adjacent points are lower. If so, it is (at least) a local minimum. Using this method is doable but it needs some hard work.

Comment: although your command ia a great help is not excactly waht I need, because it gives the local maximums (for example it gives at x=45 also a maximum but I need the maximums at x=38 and x=51). I do not need the local maximum but the next bigger maximum till the absolute maximum in asceding order and the next bigger maximum after the absolute maximum (x=32) in desceding order. To make it more clear (although it is not clear at the pictures) I need the values at x=10/21/25/31 and after x=31 (which is the absolute maximum) the values at x=35/38/51/67/95

Comment: I think that you will need to present a **formal mathematical** definition of what you are looking for. See? You are mentioning the points for which you need the maximum, meaning, you can just type them in. I guess that you actually need a mechanism that will **work** with this data and any new data as well. To that end, you must have (and provide) a clear formal definition. If you are able to phrase such definition, post it here and I'll have a look. Sorry I cannot help you any further at this point. By the way, since I **did** answer your question, you may consider up-voting it.

Comment: first of all thank you for your time and effort to answer my quastion. You provided an answer which finds the local maximum but I never asked that. So far I cannot vote your answer as a solution to my problem. The mathematical definition was already presented. Here once more: till the absolute maximum of y-axis  I need the maxima values in asceding order and after the absolute value of the y-axis I need the maxima values in descending order. Not the local maxima values but the envelope.

Comment: For example between 38 and 51 the value 43 sholud not appear as it s a local maximum and it is smaller than the neighboring maximum values. Once more: till the absolute maximum searched is the next maximum value and after the absolute maximum searched is the 2nd, 3rd, etc. maximum. Your command gives all the local maximums, which is not what I am searching, as I do not need all of them.

Comment: I'm believe you are missing an important point. Mathematically speaking, you have **one and only one** absolute maximum, and **zero or more** local maxima. Unless you provide a **FORMAL** definition of which local maxima should be considered and which should not, your problem is no solvable.